# Google Play Console not linking with Developer Api

Tags: android, google-api, google-developers-console

I am trying to get the OAuth2 Playground to return a receipt for a purchase made on our flutter app, however I've been unable to successfully get it to work.

I have all the required information

```
ProjectID = com.myorg.myapp
ProductID = myapp.funds.five
PurchaseToken = TokenValueGoesHere
```

I authorize, get to the point of "Configure request to API", I fill out the appropriate url

```
https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[ProjectID]/purchases/products/[ProductID]/tokens/[PurchaseToken]
```

however, the playground returns with

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-length: 423
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 12:52:26 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
    "code": 403, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "projectNotLinked", 
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.", 
        "domain": "androidpublisher"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We double and triple checked to ensure that the API is linked. I've created new products after the linking because I've seen others have to do that. We believe the service account has the correct permissions.

What am I missing and how do I fix this so I can verify the receipt of a purchase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so the project WAS linked properly and the error was at best vague as to what the actual problem was, in being that the OAUTH credential I was providing the playground wasn't sufficient to pull the information.

I ended up solving the issue in code.

```
@GetMapping("/verifyPurchase/app/appName={appName}&productId={productId}&purchaseToken={purchaseToken}")
public boolean isPurchaseSuccessful(@PathVariable(value = "appName") String appName,
                                    @PathVariable(value = "productId") String productId,
                                   @PathVariable(value = "purchaseToken") String purchaseToken) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    // Build service account credentials, important to include the scope which you can get from googles documentation
    GoogleCredentials serviceAccountCredentials =
            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/auth.json")) // Service Account Credentials json file from Google cloud
                    .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"));
    
    // Android publisher object, slightly older version but does operate as of 2023-Jan-26
    AndroidPublisher androidPublisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            new HttpCredentialsAdapter(serviceAccountCredentials)
    ).setApplicationName(appName).build(); // Give it the application to build the publisher for.
    
    // At this point we're authorized. We can pull down the receipt from the API, and provide the publisher
    // with the appropriate product information and purchase token that we got when we made the purchase from the
    // flutter application side of things.
    var receipt = androidPublisher.purchases().products().get(appName, productId, purchaseToken).execute();
    
    // return if the purchase was successful, may need error handling here testing to come.
    return PURCHASED.equals(receipt.getPurchaseState());
}
```